# #include repetition

Tags: c++, include-guards

**Context**: I've got one class which has two `include` clauses:

```
#ifndef VAR_RECORD_SONG_H
#define VAR_RECORD_SONG_H

#include "VarRecord.h"
#include "Compressor.h"

class VarRecordSong : public VarRecord
{
    public:
        VarRecordSong();
        ~VarRecordSong();
};

#endif /* VAR_RECORD_SONG_H */
```

**Problem**: both `VarRecord.h` and `Compressor.h` include the same file `GlobalConstants.h`, so obviously the compiler complains.

Comment: Put [Include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to `GlobalConstants.h` as you did for `VarRecordSong.h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file GlobalConstants.h should be like this:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_CONSTANTS_H
#define GLOBAL_CONSTANTS_H

file contents...

#endif
```

So this file will only appear once in the pre-processed codes.